# Apache/2.4.6 default prefork MPM configuration on Centos 7

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

Where can I find the default MPM configuration? I expect to see something like this, either on `httpd.conf` or `conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`, but there isn't such a thing in neither of them:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareServers       6
    MaxSpareServers      12
    MaxClients           60
    MaxRequestsPerChild  3000
</IfModule>
```

The `00-mpm.conf` looks like this:

```
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines:

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

Where can I find the default configuration for prefork MPM?

Comment: i think you have to add it by yourself. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/tunning-apache-but-setting-not-found-4175531918/

Answer (score 1):

I think these sections have been removed and each directive has a default for each MPM type.
See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html